# Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in

Tags: php

I need to update legacy php code 5x to 7 I am having a hard time figuring this part out

I pasted the full code here. it keeps saying line 139 sting issue and when i updated the code then another issue pops up

```
 <?php
// $Id

if (get_drupal_version() == 5) {
  require_once("drupal5_methods.php");
}
else {
  require_once("drupal6_methods.php");
}


function _phptemplate_variables($hook, $vars = array()) {
  switch ($hook) {
    case 'node':
      $vars['template_files'] = array('node-'. $vars['nid']);
      break;
    case 'page':
      if (isset($vars['node'])) {
        $vars['template_files'][] = 'page-'. str_replace('_', '-', $vars['node']->type);
        }
    break;
  }
  return $vars;
}

/* Common methods */

function get_drupal_version() { 
    $tok = strtok(VERSION, '.');
    //return first part of version number
    return (int)$tok[0];
}

function get_page_language($language) {
  if (get_drupal_version() >= 6) return $language->language;
  return $language;
}

function get_full_path_to_theme()
{
  return base_path().path_to_theme();
}

/**
 * Allow themable wrapping of all breadcrumbs.
 */
function art_breadcrumb_woker($breadcrumb) {
  $breadcrumb = menu_get_active_breadcrumb();
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    return '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' | ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
  }
}

/**
 * Allow themable wrapping of all comments.
 */
function art_comment_woker($content, $type = null) {
  static $node_type;
  if (isset($type)) $node_type = $type;
  return '<div id="comments">'. $content . '</div>';
}

/*
 * Split out taxonomy terms by vocabulary.
 *
 * @param $node
 *   An object providing all relevant information for displaying a node:
 *   - $node->nid: The ID of the node.
 *   - $node->type: The content type (story, blog, forum...).
 *   - $node->title: The title of the node.
 *   - $node->created: The creation date, as a UNIX timestamp.
 *   - $node->teaser: A shortened version of the node body.
 *   - $node->body: The entire node contents.
 *   - $node->changed: The last modification date, as a UNIX timestamp.
 *   - $node->uid: The ID of the author.
 *   - $node->username: The username of the author.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function art_terms_worker($node) {
  $output = '';
  if (isset($node->links)) {
    $output = '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;';
  }
  $terms = $node->taxonomy;
  
  if ($terms) {
    $links = array();
    ob_start();?><img class="metadata-icon" src="<?php echo get_full_path_to_theme(); ?>/images/PostTagIcon.png" width="18" height="18" alt="PostTagIcon"/> <?php
    $output .= ob_get_clean();
    $output .= t('Tags: ');
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
      $links[] = l($term->name, taxonomy_term_path($term), array('rel' => 'tag', 'title' => strip_tags($term->description)));
    }  
    $output .= implode(', ', $links);
    $output .= ', ';
  }
  
  $output = substr($output, 0, strlen($output)-2); // removes last comma with space
  return $output;
}

/**
 * Return a themed set of links.
 *
 * @param $links
 *   A keyed array of links to be themed.
 * @param $attributes
 *   A keyed array of attributes
 * @return
 *   A string containing an unordered list of links.
 */
function art_links_woker($links, $attributes = array('class' => 'links')) {
  $output = '';

  if (count($links) > 0) {
    $output = '';

    $num_links = count($links);
    $index = 0;

    foreach ($links as $key => $link) {
      $class = $key;

      if (strpos ($class, "read_more") !== FALSE) {
        break;
      }
      
      // Automatically add a class to each link and also to each LI
      if (isset($link['attributes']) && isset($link['attributes']['class'])) {
        $link['attributes']['class'] .= ' ' . $key;
      }
      else {
        
        $link['attributes']['class'] = $key;
        
      }

      if ($index > 0) {
        $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;';
      }
      
      // Add first and last classes to the list of links to help out themers.
      $extra_class = '';
      if ($index == 1) {
        $extra_class .= 'first ';
      }
      if ($index == $num_links) {
        $extra_class .= 'last ';
      }

      if ($class) {
        if (strpos ($class, "comment") !== FALSE) {
          ob_start();?><img class="metadata-icon" src="<?php echo get_full_path_to_theme(); ?>/images/PostCommentsIcon.png" width="18" height="18" alt="PostCommentsIcon"/> <?php
          $output .= ob_get_clean();
        }
        else {
          ob_start();?><img class="metadata-icon" src="<?php echo get_full_path_to_theme(); ?>/images/PostCategoryIcon.png" width="18" height="18" alt="PostCategoryIcon"/> <?php
          $output .= ob_get_clean();
        }
      }

      $index++;
      $output .= get_html_link_output($link);
    }
  }
  
  return $output;
}

function get_html_link_output($link) {
  $output = '';
  // Is the title HTML?
  $html = isset($link['html']) && $link['html'];
  
  // Initialize fragment and query variables.
  $link['query'] = isset($link['query']) ? $link['query'] : NULL;
  $link['fragment'] = isset($link['fragment']) ? $link['fragment'] : NULL;

  if (isset($link['href'])) {
    $output = l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link['attributes'], $link['query'], $link['fragment'], FALSE, $html);
  }
  else if ($link['title']) {
  //Some links are actually not links, but we wrap these in <span> for adding title and class attributes
    if (!$html) {
      $link['title'] = check_plain($link['title']);
    }
    $output = $link['title'];
  }
  
  return $output;
}

/**
 * Returns the rendered local tasks. The default implementation renders them as tabs.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function art_menu_local_tasks() {
  $output = '';

  if ($primary = menu_primary_local_tasks()) {
    $output .= $primary;
  }
  if ($secondary = menu_secondary_local_tasks()) {
    $output .= $secondary;
  }
  return $output;
}

/**
 * Format the forum body.
 *
 * @ingroup themeable
 */
function art_content_replace($content) {
  $first_time_str = '<div id="first-time"';
  $article_str = 'class="article"';
  $pos = strpos($content, $first_time_str);
  if($pos !== false)
{
    $output = str_replace($first_time_str, $first_time_str . $article_str, $content);
    $output = <<< EOT
<div class="Post">
        <div class="Post-body">
    <div class="Post-inner">
    
<div class="PostContent">
    
      $output

    </div>
    <div class="cleared"></div>
    

    </div>
    
        </div>
    </div>
    
EOT;
  }
  else 
{
    $output = $content;
  }
  return $output;
}
```

put website is still super off. any help is much appreciated it's this part here that I belive is causing the issue

```
 $link['attributes']['class'] = $key;
```

error message (from original script)
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in template.php on line 135

when I add var_dum[($links) in this part of the code

```
   // Automatically add a class to each link and also to each LI
      if (isset($link['attributes']) && isset($link['attributes']['class'])) {
        $link['attributes']['class'] .= ' ' . $key;
      }
      else {
        var_dump($links);
        $link['attributes']['class'] = $key;
        
      }

      if ($index > 0) {
        $output .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;';
      }
```

I get

**array(4) { ["links"]=> array(1) { ["home"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(35) "Home" ["href"]=> string(7) "" ["html"]=> bool(true) ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(4) "Home" } } } ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(12) "toolbar-home" } ["heading"]=> array(0) { } ["theme_hook_original"]=> string(5) "links" } array(4) { ["links"]=> array(1) { ["home"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(35) "Home" ["href"]=> string(7) "" ["html"]=> bool(true) ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(4) "Home" } } } ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(12) "toolbar-home" } ["heading"]=> array(0) { } ["theme_hook_original"]=> string(5) "links" } array(4) { ["links"]=> array(1) { ["home"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(35) "Home" ["href"]=> string(7) "" ["html"]=> bool(true) ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(4) "Home" } } } ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(12) "toolbar-home" } ["heading"]=> array(0) { } ["theme_hook_original"]=> string(5) "links" } array(4) { ["links"]=> array(1) { ["home"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(35) "Home" ["href"]=> string(7) "" ["html"]=> bool(true) ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(4) "Home" } } } ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["id"]=> string(12) "toolbar-home" } ["heading"]=> array(0) { } ["theme_hook_original"]=> string(5) "links" }
Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in template.php on line 135**

Comment: Show `var_dump($link);`

Comment: it did something now i am getting this whole thing array(1) { ["home"]=> array(4) { ["title"]=> string(35) "Home" ["href"]=> string(7) "" ["html"]=> bool(true) ["attributes"]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(4) "Home" } } } array(1) { ["id"]=> string(12) "toolbar-home" } array(0) { } string(5) "links" ........ thank you for your help tho. I'll look into this tommarow to burned out lol

Comment: can you show your full code

Comment: @jerson I pasted the full code now.

Comment: Please add the complete error message

Comment: @Vel as you can see, sometimes `$link` is a string, but you still treat it as array in your code.

Comment: @zerkms how can I tell drupal to distinguish those two things.

Comment: can you test `$link` before treating it as an array, to make sure it is an array?
`if(is_array($link)) {...`